# How Can I Save Link Which Cached Page (ASP .NET OutputCache)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I use ASP.NET MVC outputcache mechanism. But i need to save link which it's requested. But if a page is cached so i can't save the link because controller's code is bypassed of course. What can i do in this situation i need your advise...

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue, VaryByCustom = "none", VaryByParam = "")]
public ActionResult MyCachedPage(string myQueryString)
{
    //This code runs just one because the page has been cached after one hit
    //But i need to save Request.RawUrl to db. I need your advice
    _myService.SaveLink(Request.RawUrl)
}
```

Comment: Why not do the caching on the `myQueryString` itself. In that way, if a `myQueryString` has been previously allowed, then it will be cached. If a new `myQueryString` is sent, then it will be processed by the method.

Comment: You can think it search history. I need to count of search term and search terms might be same. for example if alot of customer can search "blue shoe" but the search page is cached and controller doesn't trigger to increase search counter. But i'm trying to GetVaryByCustomString method may be i can save the counter to db.

Comment: in addition customers can come from google or another referer sites so i can't use another controller for tracking.

Comment: Ahh I see, you could use an AJAX based tracker which will hit a controller action using AJAX probably on `window.onload`

Comment: yes you are right but there are some redirectings and i couldn't use window.onload. but my way  has been worked. i used GetVaryByCustomString  method to catch url so if it matchs i save it to db. there is no problem now. thanks for your comments.